# Unable to resume KVM guest after rebooting host

Tags: linux, virtual-machine, linux-kvm, qemu, libvirt

I'm running KVM on Linux Mint 17.1, kernel 3.16.0-31-generic. The only guest is a Windows 8.1 VM. I've noticed that if I reboot the host while the guest is running, I'm unable to resume the guest after the host has restarted. Virt-manager just shows the VM as "Suspended", with no power or resume option available. `virsh` also gives an error when I try to resume it:

```
zach@koln ~ $ virsh list
Id    Name                           State
----------------------------------------------------
2     windows8                       pmsuspended

~ $ virsh resume 2
error: Failed to resume domain 2
error: Requested operation is not valid: domain is pmsuspended
```

The only solution I've found is to kill the qemu process, which is less than ideal. I don't care if the VM state is discarded when I reboot the host, I'd just prefer that it start back up automatically.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is my understanding (see [this Launchpad bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/virt-manager/+bug/1174672)) that *pmsuspended* guests could only be woken up via CLI (not from GUI), via the following command:

```
  virsh dompmwakeup 2
```

As far as I know, this bug has not been corrected yet, but at least the CLI command works, it certainly does on my Kubuntu host.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, the problem was i was out of space. So I had to cleanup and free space in my home directory. And everything works perfectly as before.
Hope this help!